# Multiple programs boot and sendkeys alternative

Tags: windows, vbscript, hotkeys, sendkeys

I'm trying to execute a VBScript by a Logitech UberOptions hotkey, but of course, because of the SendKeys numberlock bug, the nice <s>little</s> **huge** Logitech NumLock toggle graphic strews itself over my screen. It doesn't look pretty. I assume an alternative to SendKeys would remedy that.

However, a real problem exists when the vbs tries to boot 2 exe's. It properly launches WOMic AND Jarvis, but Jarvis force closes milliseconds after the boot, WOmic still remains.

The final line of code is where I "auto-connect" to my microphone server (on my android) through the menu bar of the WOMic GUI.

What's an alternative to SendKeys in this scenario?

Here is my script:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\JARVIS\CustomizeableJarvis.exe""")
WScript.Sleep 250
oShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\WOMic\womicclient.exe""")
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.AppActivate "WO Mic Client 2.10"
WScript.Sleep 100
oShell.SendKeys "%cc~"
```

Comment: If you mean [this](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/179987) then your program doesn't trigger that bug.  Sounds like there might be a design fault in the Logitech software that displays the graphic in question; have you considered uninstalling it?

Comment: @HarryJohnston It has the same undesired effect when I separate the SendKeys into three commands. So it must be toggling the Numlock.

Comment: Sure, but that's not a bug, it is the expected behaviour.  If you're going to insert artificial keystrokes, you first have to normalize the state of the keyboard.  In this case none of the keystrokes you're sending depend on the state of numlock, so I suppose you could skip that step - you'll have to write your own code to do so, though, using the [SendInput function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @HarryJohnston Is that the most effective alternative to SendKeys then? Could you write an example of the SendInput function?

Answer (score 1):

Totally forgot about this post, I suppose I can answer my own question now.

Anyone viewing this should just opt to use AutoHotKey. MUCH better to accomplish what I was trying to do.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14154297)

Comment: It was only a bug within my version of Logitech SetPoint that was triggered when using SendKeys. AHK bypasses that issue.